# jquery or php wrap inside block but exclude span

Tags: php, jquery

I have html in block-level tags; I have search results that wrap sentences with matches in tags, like so:

```
<p>
Some text. More text. <span class=match>Sentence with match.</span> More text.
</p>
```

My goal is to hide (not remove) the non-matching text. I think what might work best is to wrap the non-matching text and css style it:

```
<p>
<span class=nomatch>Some text. More text. </span><span class=match>Sentence with match.</span><span class=nomatch> More text.</span>
</p>
```

Sort of invert-wrap. But how do I do that? I can use jquery or php, but it must be DOM-safe, and the paragraphs might be any block elements.

So something like (this is made up):

```
$('.match').wrapOutside()
```

**EDIT:**
I think people are right and I need to do the "nomatch" tagging in the same code I use to tag the match.

Comment: I'd like to see the code you already have that adds the `<span class=match>`. That would help me determine how best to handle the non-matched text.

Comment: I use php to split the blocks into sentences (using a regex), then check each sentence for a match. The "span" is a unique inline tag, so I don't have to worry about improperly nested tags

Comment: 1.) You have a different definition of "show me the code" than I do. I understand what you're doing/trying to do, but I'd like to actually see the code to best fit a code change/addition for your code base and requested solution. However, if you cannot show the code (for legal reasons, NDA, etc.) that's fine, but you should state that.

2.) When dealing with HTML, you should *always* be worried about improperly nested tags (in general). The non-strictness of HTML can often cause issues when one relaxes their vigilance.

Comment: Maybe you are right about "show me the code" but there are a lot of side-issues in there (dealing with search string, with paragraphs marked inactive, etc) and it would take a lot of energy to make it presentable...

Answer (score 0):

To hide it, you can just give the nomatch class the CSS property display:none. You can throw in some javascript to make it fade in when you hover or click somewhere to see more context too.

Comment: I need a way to add the nomatch spans. So given the first block of code, how do I make the second with jquery or php?

Comment: Add an else to your match code:

ex. if(match){surround with display span}else{surround with hide span}

Comment: I don't think this works: if you make the parent display:none, then the child, here the span class=match can't be made "display:inline" -- it gets hidden as well. You can have the parent by visibility:none and then the child visibility:visible, but this leaves all the space where the hidden text is...

Comment: Would you mind posting a small snippet of the code you are using to match the text?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. Replace `$('p')` with any selector you want.

```js
$('p').each(function() {
    $.each(this.childNodes, function(i, child) {
        if (child.nodeType == 3) { // text node
            $(child).before(
                $('<span class="nomatch"></span>').text(child.data)
            ).remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This is very interesting, but doesn't it assume the text that is not in the "match" span has no HTML code? But there might be bold, italics, spans, etc...

Comment: @JamieKatz This approach quickly becomes ugly if you have tags in your text other than `.match`. A match can be inside a structure like `<em>No match! <b>Half match! <span class="match">12345</span>.</b>...</em>`. Still possible: recursively add `.nomatch` to everything, then remove `.nomatch` from all `.match`es and their parents. But does it worth it? I believe you should rethink your problem.